# Problem in topology (base, inherited topology, first-countable space, convergence)

Tags: general-topology

I am a beginner in topology. Could someone help me with this problem please?

> Let there be set $X= \{1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3,...\} \cup \{ -\frac {1}{2}, -\frac {1}{3}, -\frac {1}{4}, -\frac {1}{5},...\}$.
>   There is a family of subsets of a set $X$: $B= \{U_{a,b}\ |\ a,b \in X,\ a<b\}$ and $U_{a,b}=\{x \in X\ |\ a<x<b\}$. $\tau_{B}$ is topology of base $B$.
>
> 1. Let $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the subspace topology on set $X$ inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Show: $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ is finer than $\tau_{B}$.
> 2. Show: subspace X with topology $\tau_{B}$ is first-countable.
> 3. Is sequence $a_n=- \frac{1}{n}$ convergent in $\tau_{B}$ or $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please tell us where you encountered the question (is this a homework assignment / free reading etc.), and what approaches you've tried?

Comment: It's an exercise from an old exam. My idea for 1. question is that $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ is actually discrete topology in $X$, because inherited topology is a intersection of a euclidean topology in $\mathbb{R}$ and set $X$, so every element in $X$ is isolated and because of that $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ is discrete in $X$. I also know that discrete topology is the finest topology that can be given on a set and that's why it's finer than $\tau_{B}$. But I am not sure if my idea is correct.

Comment: That's right, which answers 1 + the relevant half of 3. What can be said of $\tau_B$, for the rest?

Comment: Well, for 2. question I know that space X is said to be first-countable if each point has a countable neighbourhood basis (local base), but I don't know how to find a proper countable neighbourhood basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you say, the subspace topology $\tau_\mathbb{R}$ is discrete on $X$, so it's the finest topology on $X$.
2. We note that $X$ is countable, and $U_{a,b}\mapsto(a,b)\in X^2$ is injective, so $B$ is countable as well. This implies $\tau_B$ is second-countable, and in particular first-countable. Alternatively, for all $x\in X$, $x\neq 1$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is open. Also, $\{X\cap (-\frac{1}{n},2)\mid 0<n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable neighborhood basis for $x=1$.
3. As we've noted, $\tau_\mathbb{R}$ is discrete, hence only constant-tail sequences converge in it. In addition, since every singleton but $\{1\}$ is open in $\tau_B$, a non-constant-tail sequence cannot converge to any element but $x=1$. Indeed, we shall see that the sequence converges to $1$: take $u\in\tau_B$ such that $1\in u$. Hence we have $a,b\in X$, $a<1<b$, such that $U_{a,b}\subseteq u$. If $a<1$,$a\in X$ it follows that $a<0$, so there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $a<-\frac{1}{n}<1<b$, therefore $-\frac{1}{n}\in U_{a,b}\subseteq u$.